# Stackoverflow hacked? Что с сайтом случилось?

Tags: поддержка

Кто знает об этом? Скажитее хейй людииии

Comment: это анимация, нажми на значок времен

Comment: Случились девяностые)

Comment: 1 апреля случилось:-)

Comment: Первое апреля будет завтра

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов началось по UTC времени